# Adding link to head of collapsible list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to combine a collapsible list with a normal list, such as:

```
Link 1 (header)
Link 2 (header)
List header
    Link 3
    Link 4
Link 5 (header)
List header
    Link 6
    Link 7
Link 8 (header)
```

The thing is that when I add the link to the header:

```
<h3>
    <a href="link.php">My link</a>
</h3>
```

jQuery Mobile turns it into something like this:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner>
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            <a href="link.php" class="ui-link">My link</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

And this doesn't allow for the behaviour I want to take place. I basically want a mix list, with both collapsible items as well as with links, on the same top level. I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found out how to do this and it's quite a pretty solution. Inside the H3 of the collapsible block, just add the link as you normally would and give it a custom class name:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-allow-collapse="false">
    <h3>
        <a href="link.php" class="collapsible-header-link">My link</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

... and then just trigger a page change for the given URL using jQuery Mobile's [changePage()](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) function:

```
$("#my_page").live('pageinit', function (event) {
    $(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").bind("click", function (e) {
        var $link = $(this).find('.collapsible-header-link');
        if ($link.length > 0)
            $.mobile.changePage($link.attr('href'));
    });
});
```

You can add such links on as many headers as you want and it will work flawlessly. Hope this will help other having this issue. Cheers!

Comment: downgraded because the solution from *Yamil Revilla* is not deprecated and works.

Comment: added an answer with the **undeprecated code version** in my answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/27667934/1915920

Answer (score 2):

The code is old right now, .live() is deprecated, now we must use:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#my_page", function( event ) {
$(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").bind("click", function (e) {
    var $link = $(this).find('.collapsible-header-link');
    if ($link.length > 0)
        $.mobile.changePage($link.attr('href'));
 });
});
```

Sorry for my english :D 
Cheers!

Comment: `pageinit` should be substituted by `pagecreate` as stated here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/

Comment: with `pagecreate` one must leave out the `#my_page` param as stated here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/#event-create

Comment: added an answer with the **undeprecated code version** in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27667934/1915920

Answer (score 2):

This is the current undeprecated solution (*jQuery Mobile 1.4.5*):

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
  $(".ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").bind("click", function (e) {
    var $link = $(this).find('.collapsible-header-link');
    if ($link.length > 0)
        $.mobile.changePage($link.attr('href'));
  });
});
```

The other two answers from *Yamil Revilla* (using `on('pageinit', ...`) and from *ladu.luchian* (using `live(...)`) are deprecated as stated in the answers and/or comments above.